# Add files to repo from another directory

Tags: git, heroku

How do I add files to a repo from another directory on my computer?
I've been trying to push Heroku but it says I need to run bundle install from another folder and then upload the Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

try hardlinks if you want to track the file but have it present elsewhere in the system. (ln.exe)